# Failed to execute unit tests using maven : No tests executed

Tags: java, maven, testing, junit, surefire

While running unit tests using maven I am getting this exception. None of my tests is getting executed. My test classes are of format `**/*Tests.java`

```
Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.14.1:test (default-test) on project myproject: No tests were executed!  (Set -DfailIfNoTests=false to ignore this error.) -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.14.1:test (default-test) on project myproject: No tests were executed!  (Set -DfailIfNoTests=false to ignore this error.)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:212)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:116)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:80)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:120)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:355)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:155)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:584)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:216)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:160)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoFailureException: No tests were executed!  (Set -DfailIfNoTests=false to ignore this error.)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.SurefireHelper.reportExecution(SurefireHelper.java:55)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.SurefirePlugin.handleSummary(SurefirePlugin.java:169)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.AbstractSurefireMojo.executeAfterPreconditionsChecked(AbstractSurefireMojo.java:733)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.AbstractSurefireMojo.execute(AbstractSurefireMojo.java:631)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:132)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:208)
    ... 19 more
```

I am running following command to run this :

```
mvn -e test -DskipTests=false
```

The surefire plugin used is :

```
           <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.14.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <includes>
                        <include>**/*Tests.java</include>
                    </includes>
                    <skipTests>${skipTests}</skipTests>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
```

Does any one have idea why my tests are not getting executed?
I am using junit 4.8.2 and surefire 2.14.1

Comment: are you test java files under src/test/java ?

Comment: First why are you changing the default configuration of maven-surefire-plugin. Leave the defaults and use the naming schema for your unit tests like `*Test.java` and that's it. And of course check if your tests are located in  `src/test/java` ...

Comment: @kswaughs : yes they are in src/test/java

Comment: @khmarbaise : Tried changing one of the files to *Test.java. Still facing the same

Comment: Can you post an example of a Test? Do the tests use the `@Test` Annotation or the old way of (extends TestCase AND each test method starts with `test`)?

Comment: I am using @Test annotation in each test case

Comment: @user3057107 Have you also changed the configuration in your pom which means just removed it.... Best would be having a full example of your project somewhere for example on github....otherwise it's hard.

Comment: I had the same problem when I was trying to run an individual test using NetBeans (Ctrl + F6)

Comment: I am facing same issue.. did you fix your problem? I am getting this[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.2:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ myproject ---
[INFO] No sources to compile
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.10:test (default-test) @ myproject ---
[INFO] No tests to run.
[INFO] Surefire report directory: D:\git-workspace\myproject\target\surefire-reports 
event though my MyServiceTest.java is in src/test/java/... path

Comment: sry... i didn't worked on that afterwards

Comment: I am facing the same issue with TestNG. Can somebody advice?

Answer (score 1):

In my case I imported org.junit.Test instead of  org.junit.jupiter.api.Test class. Check your import:

```
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test
```