# Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.19.1:test (default-cli) on project UnitTestCourse: No tests were executed

Tags: java, maven, testing

I'm currently learning Unit Testing and until an hour ago I had no problems running the tests on my files but now for some reason I started getting this error. I already checked similar questions on this website but their solutions were no use to me.

Like this : [Failed to execute unit tests using maven : No tests executed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32069324/failed-to-execute-unit-tests-using-maven-no-tests-executed)

Here are my pom.xml and codes:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.junitdemo</groupId>
    <artifactId>UnitTestCourse</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
        <junit.jupiter.api>5.1.1</junit.jupiter.api>
   
    </properties>
    
    <build>
        <plugins>
        <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.19.1</version>
    <configuration>
        <testFailureIgnore>true</testFailureIgnore>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
</plugins>
    </build>
    
    <dependencies>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
            <version>${junit.jupiter.api}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.12</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
            <artifactId>hamcrest-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.3</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Test Code (package name seems same but this is in Test Packages, not Source Packages.)

```
package test;

import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertEquals;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;


public class HelloWorldTest {
    
    @Test
    void sayHelloToWorld(){
        
        HelloWorld helloWorld = new HelloWorld();
        
        assertEquals("Hello World!", helloWorld.sayHello(), "Say Hello to World");
    }
    
}
```

and source class

```
package test;


public class HelloWorld {
    
    public String sayHello(){
        
        return "Hello World";
    }
    
}
```

Here is the full error I'm getting

```
BUILD FAILURE
------------------------------------------------------------------------
Total time: 1.701s
Finished at: Sun Aug 15 18:17:36 EDT 2021
Final Memory: 7M/245M
------------------------------------------------------------------------
Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.19.1:test (default-cli) on project UnitTestCourse: No tests were executed!  (Set -DfailIfNoTests=false to ignore this error.) -> [Help 1]

To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.

For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
```

Comment: You need this plugin: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.maven.plugins/maven-surefire-plugin/3.0.0-M5 instead of the one you are using. And delete the dependency to JUnit4 (`junit:junit:4.12`) since you aren't using it.

Comment: I tried this now and did not work. Only difference is plugin version is now org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.10:test instead.

Comment: Are you sure you've placed the plugin inside `build.plugins.plugin` and not under `dependencies.dependency`? Please also include the full Maven build log and your directory structure. I'm not able to reproduce the error on my system. The test simply does not execute and Maven finishes without errors. However, if I add the appropriate version of the `maven-surefire-plugin`, the test runs.

Comment: I tried both options, first I tried under build, plugins and it didn't work then I tried under dependencies too but did not work either.